# PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_FILE' must be declared when writing to file using PLSQL block

Tags: plsql, oracle-xe

I am using following PLSQL procedure. To write some data into a file.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY CTEST AS '/tmpL';
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY CTEST TO PUBLIC;

DECLARE

out_File UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
CURSOR bulk_cursor IS

SELECT * FROM TSUSER.CUSTOMER;

TYPE bulk_row_type IS TABLE OF bulk_cursor%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
bulk_row bulk_row_type;

appTypeExists BINARY_INTEGER;

BEGIN
out_File := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(CTEST, 'validation_output.txt' , 'W');
OPEN bulk_cursor;
LOOP
    FETCH bulk_cursor
    BULK COLLECT INTO bulk_row LIMIT 10;

    FOR indx IN 1 .. bulk_row.COUNT
    LOOP

          dbms_output.put_line('Numbers are not in international format');
          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(out_file , 'Numbers are not in international format');

    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN bulk_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE bulk_cursor;   
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(out_file);
END;
/
```

But I am getting following exception

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_FILE' must be declared
```

I am running in this script in ORACLE XE database as the system user. What else should I do to get something written to the file ?

Answer (score 0):

log as `SYS` and execute `grant execute on utl_file to system`

Comment: btw. do not forget to set `utl_file_dir` in *init.ora*

Comment: `utl_file_dir` is deprecated. Better to create and use DIRECTORY objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the UTL_FILE privilege to the schema.

```
GRANT EXECUTE on UTL_FILE to schema_name
```